# Binary Operation with Cayley Table

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, cayley-table

I am asked to write out a Cayley table of a binary operation $\ast$ on the set $$ S = \{1, 2, 3\}$$ for which there is no solution for $\ast$ in $S$ to the equation $1 \ast x = 2$.

Here is my attempt.  Is this correct?  If $1 \ast x = 2$ has no solution in $S$, should that entry in the Cayley table be empty or can it be some other integer outside of $S$, i.e. 4,5, or 6?

\begin{array}{cc|c|c|c|}
* && 1 & 2 & 3\\
&&&&\\
\hline
1 &&  &  & \\
\hline
2 && 1 & 3 & 2\\
\hline
3 && 2 & 1 & 3\\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"No solution to $1*x=2$ means that $2$ can not appear in the first row of your Cayley table; if $2$ appeared, that would mean that $1$ star something is equal to $2$.

Comment: So does that mean the first row could be filled with just 1's or 3's?

Comment: @mathamphetamines Yes, that means we can only see $1$'s or $3$'s in the first row, provided $S$ is closed under the operation of $*$. The wording makes it seem as if this is the case.